# Emulator SD card Partition

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible to create partitions on SD card from the emulator.

Comment: Please let me know what all partitions are supported by the android hardware.

Comment: By partitions do you mean folders, or something else ?????

Comment: Real partitions like ext or fat.

Comment: I hope since the Android core is Linux version 2.6,it supports all those file systems supported by the Linux 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to do it. What you need first is a sd card or usb drive then plug it in your computer. I use Linux so let's say after that there is a new device in /dev named /dev/sdb.
Use a partition tool (eg fdisk for linux) to create the partitions. When you're done, make a copy of /dev/sdb with dd (dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdcard.img).

That's all. You can now launch your emulator with your new sdcard.